# can't btree index function that returns text

Tags: postgresql

I've created a function to index a certain value from another table.
basically, i'm querying these activities, often filtered on the context of the activityplans table.

this is my function:

```
 CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_activity_context(parentact uuid, parentplan uuid) RETURNS TEXT
        LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
    $$

    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN $2 is not null THEN
        (select LOWER((("context")::json->>'href')::text) from activityplans ap where ap.key = $2)
    WHEN $1 is not null THEN
        (select LOWER((("context")::json->>'href')::text) from activityplans ap, activities act where act."parentPlan" = ap.key AND act.key=$1)
    END
    
 $$;
```

the function works, when I use it, for example, like  `select  get_activity_context("parentActivity", "parentPlan") from activities limit 10;`

but when i try to create an index:

```
 create index on activities (get_activity_context("parentActivity", "parentPlan"));
```

i get this:

```
ERROR:  could not read block 0 in file "base/16402/60840": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
CONTEXT:  SQL function "get_activity_context" during startup
SQL state: XX001
```

googling this error only bring me to database data issues etc, but i don't think this is the case. My guess is something is wrong with the function, but i can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: Your function depends on the database state (the contents of tables) and so is not truly immutable.  Lying about the immutability of a function is likely to cause bad things to happen.

Comment: Are you able to create index manually I mean without `(get_activity_context("parentActivity", "parentPlan"))` ?

Comment: @mLipok yes other indexes can be created just fine.

Comment: You said yes about other indexes, but I was thinking about exactly the one which you get using `select  get_activity_context("parentActivity", "parentPlan") from activities limit 10;` which as you said works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which relation 60840 is in your database, but it sure has a problem. Find out with

```
SELECT relname,relnamespace::regnamespace
FROM pg_class
WHERE relfilenode = 60840;
```

Anyway, that index will never work, because the function is *not* `IMMUTABLE`, no matter how you declared it. It may return a different result tomorrow. This would lead to data corruption.

An index on one table can never refer to data from another table.

Comment: the select returns 0 records. the number is always incremented by one, when i'm trying. I have also managed to make a hash index on this. but simply not a btree.

Comment: it's not theoretically immutable, but it is practically immutable.

Comment: Then it's probably the index itself that gets. Concerning your second comment: Are you sure that this will still be the case when you restore parts of the database from a `pg_dump`? Anyway, that's too dangerous a thing to do. Don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought:

Usually index are created like this:

```
CREATE INDEX id_column_idx 
    ON public.naleznosc USING btree
    (id_column)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

but you, are trying to create them this way:

```
CREATE INDEX .......... on activities ...........(get_activity_context("parentActivity", "parentPlan")) ...........;
```

The dots showing places where you not put some things :)

Comment: it is a valid way of creating an index. the name can be generated. btree is the default.

Comment: but where you have IndexName in your code snippet ?

Comment: i don't. postgres will use a default name.

Comment: Postgres doesn't require a name to be specified when creating an index